# How to extract only rows with maxdate for specific part of query?

Tags: sql-server, sorting, date, filter, max

I'd like to sort out only rows with the max date of a specific combination of values.
The basic query gives the (all) results as expected, but needs to shrink down to the relevant informations.
I have a combination of receip numbers, article numbers, calculation-schemes with some (up tp 22) positions and  for each article at least one container-no. can be up to eight.
Our employees can do a calculation with our erp-system at any day they like for a article-container-combination.
So it could be that for the same combination more than one calculation-date ist stored.

This is the basic-query for all:

```
SELECT 
    T1."NUMMER" "Rezeptnummer",
    T1."BEZEICHNUNG1" "Rezeptbezeichnung",
    T3."SUMMEMATERIALWERTL" "Rezept Materialwert L",
    T15."NUMMER" "Kalkulationsschema-Nr",
    T15."BEZEICHNUNG" "Kalkulationsschema-Bez",
    T13."KALKULATIONSDATUM" "Kalkulationsdatum",
    T14."POSNR" "Kalkulationsposition",
    T14."BEZEICHNUNG" "Kalkulationsposition-Bez",
    T14."VOLLKOSTENHUNDERTME" "Vollkosten Hundert ME",
    T14."BASISBEWERTUNGSKOSTEN" "Basis Bewertungskosten Proz.",
    T14."BASISVOLLKOSTEN" "Basis Vollkosten Proz.",
    T17."NUMMER" "Artikelummer",
    T17."BEZEICHNUNG1" "Artikelbezeichnung",
    T19."EMBALLAGENNUMMER" "Emballagennummer",
    T19."EMBALLAGENBEZEICHNUNG" "Emballagenbezeichnung"
FROM 
     dibac.CORE_EMBALLAGE T21
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN dibac.CORE_ARTIKELGEBINDE T19 ON T21.INTID = T19.INTID_EMBALLAGE
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dibac.CORE_ARTIKEL T17 ON T19.INTID_ARTIKEL = T17.INTID
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN dibac.CORE_VORKALKULATION T13 ON T17.INTID = T13.INTID_ARTIKEL
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dibac.CORE_REZEPT T1 ON T13.INTID_REZEPT = T1.INTID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dibac.T_MD_STATE T2 ON T1.STRUID_NUCLOSSTATE = T2.STRUID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dibac.CORE_REZEPTPOSITION T3 ON T1.INTID = T3.INTID_REZEPT
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dibac.CORE_VORKALKULATIONPOSITION T14 ON T13.INTID = T14.INTID_VORKALKULATION
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dibac.CORE_PARAMETERDATENQUELLE T20 ON T14.INTID_DATENQUELLE = T20.INTID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dibac.CORE_KALKULATIONSSCHEMA T15 ON T13.INTID_KALKULATIONSSCHEMA = T15.INTID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dibac.T_MD_STATE T18 ON T17.STRUID_NUCLOSSTATE = T18.STRUID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dibac.T_MD_STATE T22 ON T21.STRUID_NUCLOSSTATE = T22.STRUID
WHERE 
    (t1.nummer = '20091') AND 
    (t2.intnumeral = '40') AND 
    (t3.summematerialwertl > 0 ) AND 
    (t18.intnumeral = '50') AND 
    (t19.emballagennummer NOT IN ('000', 'RST', 'MUS', 'ZZZ', '109')) AND 
    (t22.intnumeral = '40')
ORDER BY 
    t1.nummer ASC,
    t13.kalkulationsdatum DESC,
    t19.emballagennummer ASC
```

(t1.nummer = '20091') gives 704 rows back, full run more than 91.000 rows. Guess filtering to the needed informations, this will be about 20.000.

I "just" need the very last of each - and tried since days with almost anything i could find and understand ...select with ties, row_number etc. anything i thought it could help to solve the problem - which is also depending on my deeper knowledge of MS-SQL.
The query uses about 19 tables with joins and gives about 15 columns back.
With some of my tests it works -almost- as expected for -one- article-number, but not if i fire it to -all-.
My Example-Article should give back 44 lines (full run gives 704 which is 32 calculation on serveral dates containing 22 positions) because this article has only two container-nos.
So there was a calculation on 3rd of March for container 001 (22 positions)
and a calculation on 1st of March for container 002 (also 22 positions given from calculation-rule).
In the past for any of this container are some more calculations in the databse but to me only the very last calculation of each is important.

Comment: What did you try with `ROW_NUMBER`? Can you show sample data and or construct a https://dbfiddle.uk showing the issue?

Comment: Row_number over partition...- this was working for the example, but not for articles with more containers than two. I'll post the examples tomorrow from the bigger machine, i'ts easier. It might be that i not completely understand the effects of partition by and order by in this specific context.

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t17.nummer ORDER BY t13.Kalkulationsdatum asc, t19.emballagennummer asc)

was one of the tries in the order by section, SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES in the beginning. I played around, because working for my example, but fails when firing it to the whole database.

Comment: Please add code into your post using the [edit] button, not in comments, it's too hard to read.

Comment: For now its almost solved. There is another issue now. Because i'm not that perfect to edit here the way i'd like to, i guess 'll open another question prepared with code an screenshots.

Comment: The [edit] button is right there, but if you have a new question then post as a new one. Do not post screenshots

Comment: After long time (i do queries just parttime) i'd like to present he solution.
basically the issue was first: wrong command to FORMAT the date. needs to be CONVERT with Code 104. Next step was to use MAX and GROUP BY. So i got the result i needed.